# Not able to deploy through Firebase

Tags: firebase, backend, firebase-hosting

[not getting hosted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m45fx.png)

[main directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nffzG.png)
[inside public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGDdA.png)

I have followed every step in order to deploy the project through firebase.
I have even included the copy of all the files inside public folder but I am not able to see my app getting hosted .
I think I am making some mistake regarding the location of files

I was trying to host my project through heroku so I had made some changes from there like I switched the port to

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log("our server is running on port 3000");
});
```

and adding a Procfile , inside which I have written

```
web:node app.js
```

I am just a beginner to web dev , So I am unfamiliar with a alot of things , I think I have made a very silly mistake here

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not run backend JavaScript.  It only serves static content.  If you want to host a web project with a nodejs backend, you will need to use another product.  Cloud Functions is supported.  See the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions